# How can I debug why fans are constantly spinning?

Tags: macos, hardware, sleep-wake, cpu

OK, I admit a 5.5+ yr old MacBook Air is a bit dated, but I am not overloading it.

Nonetheless, the constantly spinning fans are more than a bit of an annoyance.

However, I do want to understand *why* it is behaving this way.

I regularly see (in `top`) 50-75% idle, and with a load average of 4-6. However, at times it has a much higher load average, more like 7-8, particularly when fans are spinning. Whenever I wake it from sleep (lift the lid), I can see an idle of 0% and a load average of 70-80, and sometimes over 100 (!!) for a few minutes.

I grew up (professionally) on Unix, so very comfortable with usual commands, as well as dtrace scripts. I could use some pointer in figuring out how to get a machine that is, all in all, running Chrome, Safari, Dropbox, iTerm2, TextMate2, Twitter, Slack and that is it to more normal behaviour.

Comment: First guess would be fluffy fans... when was the last time it was stripped & cleaned?

Comment: Far too long ago! :-) In all seriousness, you probably are right, as to part of the problem. "Fluffy" = "full of dust"? On the other side, I do see incredibly high load averages at times, so I would like to track that down too. In the meantime, will open the Air up and clean the fans on Sunday.

Comment: BTW, finally picked up the toolkit last week, stripped and cleaned. Still spinning, but noticeably less.

Comment: Now if only I could figure out (a) why Excel is beachball stuck (stress shows only ~140 syscalls during the period, near the bottom) and (b) why Twitter and Slack have lots of console errors from keychain